# Rendering only one frame instead of whole animation

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine

I'm new to animation and have seen the previous post on this topic, but changing the settings did not work for me. My file is only rendering one still frame in video format with these settings. I'm rendering in cycles if that helps.

The end goal is to have a video that shows this throw blowing in the wind.

I've attached the information I think is useful. So grateful for anyone that can help.

[image]

Comment: Do you start your rendering with F12 or Ctrl+F12? F12 is for rendering single frames, Ctrl+F12 for rendering animations (image sequences or in your case a video).

Comment: I've been using Ctrl f12, or "render animation" instead of an image. It will look like it's rendering but while it's rendering each frame, the frames aren't changing, it's just rendering the same image over and over again until all of the frames have been rendered.

Comment: Well, then the interesting thing is what should actually happen in the video? There is no information on that in the question. From what I see in the screenshot it could be some cloth simulation with wind. Did you bake the simulation? Is it playing back in the _3D Viewport_? I have the strong suspicion that the problem is not rendering, but the animation itself.

Comment: Ah, okay. I haven't tried baking anything. I'm new to this so I will definitely try baking the simulation and I'll come back and report my results.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I appreciate your help tonight. I went to object -> animation -> bake action and entered the 160-250 frames I wanted to have been in the video. It didn't work but it did add two keyframes that are connected from beginning to end. It looks like I'll just have to do some more digging on baking. Thank you for the tip. I'm getting rest and will do my research tomorrow. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome, Sarah. _Bake Action_ won't help here, if this is an either _Cloth_ or _Soft Body_ object, you have to bake the **simulation** (not the action) inside the **physics properties** of the object. I would highly recommend to watch some tutorials about cloth, soft bodies and maybe even rigid bodies and other physics simulations in Blender.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check your animation because the rendering is fairly simply. Maybe check if the soft body, which I guess you are using, has correct settings to allow movement from the force field (wind).